# How to execute a plugin on a single page only?

Tags: plugins, css, javascript

A few basic questions to accelerate my wordpress plugin development start. I'd like to develop a wordpress plugin that adds some javascript and css to a specific page. 
What filters or actions should be used?
How to restrict execution of a plugin to a single (known) page?
How can a plugin add some content to a page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a built-in function called [wp_enqueue_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) which will allow a certain piece of JavaScript to be included in a page. If you'd just like to see that script on a particular page, you can conditionally call it from the theme file. For example:

```
<?php if (is_page('home')) {
    wp_register_script('custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . 
    '/js/custom_script.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
} ?>
```

You can do something similar with [wp_register_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to include the CSS as well.

Comment: Additionally, you can modify actions and filters within the `if` statement, that way the hooks and filters are only modified for that page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Page Specific CSS/JS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-specific-cssjs/) plugin [source code](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/page-specific-cssjs/trunk/page-specific-cssjs.php) -- This simple plugin allows you include a separate stylesheet and/or javascript file for any page on your site.